# Hyperlink in Expander of HierarchicalDataTemplate not firing HandleOnRequestNavigate event

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, treeview, expander

I think I added all the necessary parts to add custom link handling to my treeview, but when I step through the code in the debugger, I see that my code behind never gets called.

I attempted to add a hyperlink to my treeview like so:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:StructuredViewNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Reference}" RequestNavigate="HandleOnRequestNavigate" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectName}"/>
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock> 

</Grid>

</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I have the required code behind:

```
private void HandleOnRequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    // Do custom link handling
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Maybe its of interest, that the tree has a custom style, the part where the hyperlink lies is an expander defined like follows:

```
<Expander Name="Exp" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
    <Expander.Header>
        <!-- Displays the item's header in the Expander. -->
        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
    </Expander.Header>
    <StackPanel>
        <Separator Margin="5" Width="Auto" Background="{StaticResource ItemBorderBrush}" Height="6" ></Separator>
        <!-- Displays the item's children. -->
        <ItemsPresenter />
    </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

Does anybody see why my hyperlink handling code does not get called?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hyperlink takes uri as object or string; the problem is where you define your callback...must be in the StructuredViewNodel or has to be find  with relativesource binding

Comment: As soon as I changed the argument to a string it worked fine though, are you sure?

Comment: well, if Reference is an Uri class or a string it should work

Comment: It was a self defined class not extending an Uri class. My bad on that, I thought since I'm writing the link handling code myself it would not be so picky...

Comment: unfortunatetly, not. but in this case you'd better change hyperlink to another control and handle the click event or even better a command in your viewmodel

Comment: If it looks like a hyperlink and acts like a hyperlink it must be....
I think the hyperlink is a good fit for my functionality here, because I want to jump to a different window in my application when I click it. 

But if you feel like showing a simple control I would make sure to accept your answer!

Comment: well, i don't like hyperlink... you can easily customise a label (manage click) with blue foreground and cursor= hand

Comment: I like that. If you want to summarize your feedback into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks;
to summerize our exchange, hyperlink accept only valid url as Uri object or string and will fire naviguate event in that case only. In case of a businnes object, change it to a blue foreground Label control, change Cursor =Cursors.Hand, handle click event or custom MVVM command in your viewmodel. That do the trick. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that you can only have `strings` as URI. So the simplest solution seems to be to write a converter and add the object like so:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding ObjectReference,  
                         Converter={StaticResource ObjectToStringConverter}}" 
           RequestNavigate=""HandleOnRequestNavigate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectReference}"/>
</Hyperlink>
```